# Should I place function within foreach loop brackets?

Tags: php, loops

What is more effecient? Placing function within `foreach` loop...

```
    $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {

        # do whatever...
    }
```

Or specifying in a variable before:

```
    $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    $keys = array_keys($array);

    foreach ($keys as $key) {

        # do whatever...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever seems more readable.... though the latter will use slightly more memory than the former: but neither is necessary in this case as you can do:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    # do whatever...
}
```

If you only need the keys, you can use the above and simply ignore the value (though syntactically you need to specify it)

**EDIT**

If you're concerned about performance and memory usage, a quick test with an array of 256k elements (enough to give differential in the stats):

#### #1

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
}
```

gives

```
Call time was 0.0466 seconds
Current memory usage: 21.75 MB
Peak memory usage: 42.75 MB
```

#### #2

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
}
```

gives

```
Call time was 0.0335 seconds
Current memory usage: 42.75 MB
Peak memory usage: 42.75 MB
```

#### #3

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
}
```

gives

```
Call time was 0.0103 seconds
Current memory usage: 21.5 MB
Peak memory usage: 21.5 MB
```

Comment: You're looping through exactly the same values.... the overhead in memory is one zval for the `value` element (depends what datatype your values actually are), and that additional zval is retained after the loop.... For either of the other methods, the additional memory requirement is one zval for the array itself, plus one zval for each array element (each key).... if you explicitly define `$keys = array_keys($array);` then that additional memory is retained after the loop; if you use `foreach (array_keys($array) as $key)` then the additional memory is freed after the loop